# Radio selection buttons not showing up on form

Tags: html, css, forms, radio-button

I am having a problem getting radio buttons to show up on my BigCartel site using a Neartail form. Here's the form in question: https://www.invisual.group/custom-orders

I tried scanning the BigCartel CSS for any lines that may hide the radio button, but I couldn't find any - although I assume this is the problem.

I would greatly appreciate any help with this! I assume it's a simple issue but it has so far eluded me.

P.S. on my NeoCities website, the form works fine: https://darkage.online/customapparel.html

Comment: The direct cause of the buttons not appearing, is the appearance:none and webkit-appearance:none attributes. These are added by theme.css for the elements
  
    form, input, textarea, submit, input[type='submit'], input[type='text'], button, select.
  
As to how you avoid this. I'm afraid I don't know the templating system you are using, so I've added this as a comment only. Hope this is ok.

Comment: Thank you for the response!

Comment: Some more info: these attributes are via theme.css file. The full filename is https://www.invisual.group/theme_stylesheets/196239528/1641437832/theme.css - can you see that file? See the section beginng "form, input" on line 955. Try commenting out the three appearance: none entries. In CSS, surround them with slash-asterisk and asterisk-slash i.e. /* */. You may find this causes unwanted radio buttons or input elements elsewhere, so test thoroughly.

Comment: wow thanks david! it was exactly what i thought it was but couldn't seem to find it. cheers, mate!